# why my solution for leetcode 977 Squares of a Sorted Array failed

Tags: c

### Question

https://leetcode.com/problems/squares-of-a-sorted-array/

### MySolution

Since it kept showing the output is [], empty array, I printf the array to check it is correct. That has no nothing to do with the error.

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* sortedSquares(int* A, int ASize, int* returnSize){
    int * a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*ASize);
    int head = 0;
    int tail = ASize-1;
    
    for (int pos=ASize-1; pos>-1; pos--){
        if (abs(A[tail]) > abs(A[head])) {
            a[pos] = A[tail]*A[tail];
            tail--;
        } else if (abs(A[tail]) < abs(A[head])) {
            a[pos] = A[head]*A[head];
            head++;
        } else if (abs(A[tail]) == abs(A[head]) && head == tail){
            a[pos] = A[head]*A[head];
        }
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<ASize;i++){
         printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return a;
}
```

### TestCase

[-4,-1,0,3,10]

### Wrong Output

[]

### Error Message

```
=================================================================
==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x603000000054 at pc 0x000000405338 bp 0x7fffb369b090 sp 0x7fffb369b080
READ of size 4 at 0x603000000054 thread T0
    #2 0x7f78a437582f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
0x603000000054 is located 0 bytes to the right of 20-byte region [0x603000000040,0x603000000054)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f78a5390f88 in malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10bf88)
    #3 0x7f78a437582f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c067fff8000: fa fa 00 00 04 fa fa fa 00 00[04]fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==32==ABORTING
```

It hides the main function content, so I don't know what the returnSize for, which seems duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked over the problem. you have a return parameter called **returnSize** and you didn't assign it, please add before return the following line

```
*returnSize = ASize;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your bug, this'll pass though:

```
int* sortedSquares(const int* A, const int ASize, int* returnSize) {
    *returnSize = ASize;
    int* res = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * (*returnSize));
    int* head = A;
    int* tail = A + ASize - 1;
    int k = ASize - 1;

    while (head <= tail && k >= 0) {

        if (*head < 0) {
            *head = *head * -1;
        }

        if (*tail < 0) {
            *tail = *tail * -1;

        }


        if (*head >= *tail) {
            res[k] = *head * (*head);
            ++head;

        } else {
            res[k] = *tail * (*tail);
            --tail;
        }

        --k;
    }

    return res;
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/squares-of-a-sorted-array/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.